# Token issue while sending Push Notification

Tags: android, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

We are getting failure response, when we try to push a notification to FCM registered android device from azure notification hub.Below details are enclosed.

Failure response : The Token obtained from the Token Provider is wrong

FCM Registration id : `APA91bHmFBRCpF4veiYuT1XftaK7f3T73dEDO0-9KDRYSXh0tyKWHv0lsDr_pxrGRYnpTLzkhHzLHdMwD8th6knAfCd_xsxG8HX4f4Sp4fMYADFI8kNllyGglJQRh-LFJzzEU2TX5YJJ`

Then register another android device ,It receives push notification successfully.

FCM Registration id : `eCavQYTDs8c:APA91bGuBocDnUMNCwwvxt2ugCRb3vFyFkMiXihlpTOSOWXNscaVrcsmM9LoG2b6Az-H5SvKx4meUCRCsXbO6tHF2hjZCAIUtMTUkfiQIzfALbB98oGfAreVdSQGs2Q-pN203d6rfeZD`

We checked and found the difference only in registration id length.First registered device has registration id with length 141 and secound registered device has registration id with length 151.

**Is there any chance to notification failure due to registration id length.**

Comment: It does look like your first token is missing the first characters up to the colon (:).

Comment: But ,both two tokens get from FCM